# Detail on monotony table

Tags: tikz-pgf

Well here is what I finally want to achieve.

The following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]
 {$x$/1,$f'(x)$ /1, $f(x)$ /2}{$-\infty$,$0$, $1$ , $+\infty$}%
 \tkzTabLine{,+,d,-,z,+}
 \tkzTabVar[color=red]%
 { -/ $-\infty$ / ,+D+/$0$ / $+\infty$ , -/ $e$ , +/ $+\infty$}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

prodcues this motonony table.

[image]

The result is perfect. However, is it possible that the dashed line that I have under 1 displaying the zero of the derivative be extended further down till e? That is the dashed line covers also the other cell of f reaching down till e ?

I have not found something in the Altermundus manual, so I guess this cannot be done (?) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option using a `\draw` and the internal names associated to the nodes in `tkz-tab` to extend the line downwards up to the "e":

```
\draw[dotted] (N32) -- (FR32);
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=2]
 {$x$/1,$f'(x)$ /1, $f(x)$ /2}{$-\infty$,$0$, $1$ , $+\infty$}%
 \tkzTabLine{,+,d,-,z,+}
 \tkzTabVar[color=red]%
 { -/ $-\infty$ / ,+D+/$0$ / $+\infty$ , -/ $e$ , +/ $+\infty$}
\draw[dotted] (N32) -- (FR32);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you explain how the new command actually works? I don't undestand since it is the first time I see it.

Comment: @Tolaso It's a standard TikZ `\draw` command; in its simpler form you provide two coordinates and a path specification (`--` in this case, i.e., a straight line) with some optional modifier (`dotted` in my answer) and a straight dotted line is drawn joining the two coordinates.

Comment: Well, I know the command but I don't understand the number (N32)--(FR32). This is the part of the command I did not understand. Where do the numbers come in?

Comment: @Tolaso Those are the internal names of the coordinates and nodes used by the package to place the elements; some of the naming conventions used by the package author start with `F,` `S`, `N`, `FR`; you have to read the code of the package to see how each element is named.